# move the uncommited change to another branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have made some changes in project, but I **didn't commit** the changes. They are in the state of

```
Changes not staged for commit
```

. Then I realised I should make these changes in a separate branch than the current one.

How can I create a new branch which can have my current changes while remove the uncommitted changes in current branch?

Comment: Have you actually just tried to do it? Because git will just let you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checkout a new branch, commit within the new branch, and checkout the original branch. This way the changes will be in a separate branch only.

Answer (score 0):

You can type:

```
git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH_NAME
git add .
git commit -m "PUT YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE HERE"
```

`git checkout -b ...` creates a new branch and checks it out in one step.

Now you can use `git checkout master` to go back to the master branch.

To merge your code into the master branch:

```
git checkout master   # if you are not already in the master branch
git merge NEW_BRANCH_NAME
```